# I'm having a couple of errors on my bubble sorting program which displays the maximum, minimun and average (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

I'm doing a programing code for a homework, you are supposed to enter student's height to be sorted, printing the maximum, minimum the sorting result and the average, but I'm having a couple of errors, I managed to get the sorting and maximum done, but the minimum is wrong and I have to obtain the average on an array but I haven't figured out how to make the program read the values typed by the user.
I would be very thankful if someone managed to help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

    float average (float ave1, float ave2, float ave3, float ave4, float ave5, float ave6, float ave7, float ave8, float ave9, float ave10)
    {
        float result = 0;
        result = ((ave1 + ave2+ ave3 + ave4 + ave5 + ave6 + ave7 + ave8 + ave9 + ave10) /10);
        result (result);
    }
//This is my failed attempt to code the average array
int main() {
    float height[10];
    float max = 0;
    float min = 0;

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "What's student " << i + 1 <<" height?" << endl;
        cin >> height [i];
    }

    max = min = height[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) //Bubble Sort
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        if (height[j] > height [j+1])
        {float temp;

                temp = height [j];
                height [j] = height [j+1];
                height [j+1] = temp;
            if (height [i] < min)
            {
                min = height [i];
            }
            if (height [i] > max)
            {
                max = height [i];
            }
    }
    }
    height [i] = ave1 = ave2 = ave3 = ave4 = ave5 = ave6 = ave7 = ave8 = ave9 = ave10 ;

    cout << "The tallest student's height is: " << max << " feet" << endl;
    cout << "The shortest student's height is: " << min << " feet" << endl;
    cout << "Sorted heights are: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << height [i] << "; ";
    }
    cout << "Height average: " << endl;
    cout << average;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting *sorting and maximize* done when you haven't figured out how to get the input from the user yet? (Getting input from the user in C++, BTW, has been asked and answered here many times, which a little searching would find for you.) And if you can do maximum, you should be able to get minimum - it's the exact opposite.

Comment: Yes, user inputs the heights on the first "for" loop where it asks what's the student's height, the issue is that when it prints the minimum, it's not always the smallest number, for example if you enter 1.40 and 1.41, it get's 1.41 as the minimum where 1.40 should be the correct answer

Comment: No, you won't get `1.41` as the minimum, because the `<` operator works correctly with a comparison of `1.41` and `1.40` and correclty identifies `1.40` as lower. So check your code again to make sure your comparison is right. As far as user input, I took that from your question itself in *I haven't figured out how to make the program read the values typed by the use*. Averrage is just summing the values entered and then dividing by the number of inputs.

Comment: I also don't think that the line `eight [i] = ave1 = ave2 = ave3 = ave4 = ave5 = ave6 = ave7 = ave8 = ave9 = ave10;` does what you think it does, either. You may want to read your code carefully.

Comment: I think I havent made myself clear. 
When I enter 5 different heights sometimes the program wont pick the correct answer, I already know 1.41 is not the minimum, but the program picks it anyway (instead of 1.40 for example)

Comment: Also what I was trying to say is that I have no idea how to make the program read the inputs to make the algorythm that produce the average height where the formula would be for example (a+b+c)/3

Comment: You're trying to do too much at once. Comment out all the code that does anything but find the minimum. Get that working. Then add code for the maximum back, and test that both work. Then add the code back that calculates the average, and test to see if everything works at that point. When youre writing code, break things up into tasks. Start with one task, and don't add anything else until that is working properly. Then move on to the next task, and don't add anything else until that is working and you've confirmed your other s still work, and repeati to put things together.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to do it thanks, I just started coding on C++ this month

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and look into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of sorting a list of numbers in ascending order the min value Is the first item of the list and the hight value Is the last item of the list, so min=height[0] and max=height [9] after sortng.

1. In your code remove this lines:

   ```
     if (height [i] < min)
       {
           min = height [i];
       }
       if (height [i] > max)
       {
           max = height [i];
       }
   ```
2. after line:

   ```
   float min=0;
   ```

   Add:

   ```
   float acum=0;
   ```
3. Replace this line:

   ```
   height [i] = ave1 = ave2 = ave3 = ave4 = ave5 = ave6 = ave7 = ave8 = ave9 = ave10 ;
   ```

   By :

   ```
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        acum+=height[i];

    min=height[0];
    max=height[9];
   ```
4. AND finally Replace;

   ```
    cout << average;
   ```

   By

   ```
    cout<< acum/10;
   ```